# Подключение JSON из PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

У меня есть PHP файл, в котором

```
$arrayOfXY = array_map(function ($x, $y) use ($coefficient) {
   $regY = $coefficient['a'] + $coefficient['b']*$x;
   echo("${x}, ${y}, ${regY} <br>");
   return ["x" => +$x, "y" => +$y, "regY" => $regY];
}, $x_array, $y_array);
$arrayOfXY = json_encode($arrayOfXY);
$filename = 'data.json';
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fputs($fp, $arrayOfXY);
fclose($fp);
```

В JS файле:

```
am4core.ready(function () {
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.dataSource.url = "data.json";
```

Но у chart.data есть возможность напрямую задать JSON, без подргрузки из файла.
Как мне вставить туда переменную `$arrayOfXY` ?

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов: 1) Вставить в html тег script и в нём написать window.myJSON = '<?php echo $json; ?>', и потом эта переменная доступна в любых скриптах будет. Только проэкранируйте одинарные кавычки у $json. 2) Если php генерит js, то аналогично вставить в сам JS.

Comment: Добавил в конец php "echo *тут все скрипты*. Но все равно не грузит переменную в js

Comment: По вашим данным не понятна вся картина. Не ясно что за php файл у вас, где шаблон страницы, есть ли вообще страница или это php-модуль, где js файл, и что за скрипты вы пишете в конец php и зачем.